# Downloading file from s3 freezes and throws exception while network goes down temporary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using AWS S3 SDK to download a file from S3 Bucket via TransferManager.
 
Cases
1. File download is successful if there is no interruption in internet connectivity.
2. However in case of network failure  file downloading freezes for some time but resumes successfully if Internet is up before socket timeout by default(50 sec).
3.On increasing socket time out from my side

```
@Bean
public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    this.clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(600*1000);
    return this.clientConfiguration;
}
```

file downloading freezes,downloads some bytes and freezes again after internet is up after hiccup. Later it throws connection reset exception.

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to store object contents to disk: Connection reset at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadToFile(ServiceUtils.java:313)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadObjectToFile(ServiceUtils.java:270)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.retryableDownloadS3ObjectToFile(ServiceUtils.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1455)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.DownloadPartCallable.call(DownloadPartCallable.java:59)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.DownloadPartCallable.call(DownloadPartCallable.java:31)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:198)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.read(S3AbortableInputStream.java:118)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:107)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:82)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadToFile(ServiceUtils.java:307)
```

My question is how can I configure my client so that one can resume download of  a file at anytime even if the network breaks down?